# UPnP device library: android

Tags: android, upnp

has any body worked with  UPnP Library for Java By Cybergarage..

https://cgupnpjava.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/cgupnpjava/trunk/cyberlink/upnp-stack/src/main/java/org/

I am making android application to find the list of UPnP device from my device...

any help on these most appreciable../

thanks rakesh

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have a created an alternative Java UPnP library that also works on Android:

http://teleal.org/projects/cling/core/

A [manual chapter](http://teleal.org/projects/cling/core/manual/cling-core-manual.html#chapter.Android) about Android integration, an [example application](http://www.teleal.org/projects/download/misc/), and a [video of the example application](http://www.teleal.org/weblog/New%20Cling%20beta3%20runs%20on%20Android%2021.html) are available. The example application shows how you can search and list all the UPnP devices on your network.

Comment: Of possible upload a recent video.